# date validation JavaScript

Tags: javascript, validation, date

I am writing a birthday validation form with JavaScript but it doesn't work. Could you please help to find out which part is wrong? How to fix it?

JavaScript

```
function onFormSubmit(form_element) {

    var slashcount = 0;
    if ((form_element.birthday.value =="")||(form_element.birthday.value ==null))
    {
        alert("This field is required. Please enter date mm/dd/yyyy!");
        false;
    }
    for (var i=0; i < birthday.length; i++)
    {
        temp = "" + birthday.substring(i, i+1);
        if (temp == "/")
        {
            slashcount++;
        }
        if (valid.indexOf(temp) == "-1")
        {
            alert("error1.");
            false;
        }
        if (slashcount != 2)
        {
            alert("error2");
            false;
        }
        if((birthday.charAt(2)!= '/')||( birthday.charAt(5) != '/'))
        {
            alert("error3");
            false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}​
```

HTML

```
<form onsubmit="return onFormSubmit(this)">

        Birthday:<input type="text" name="birthday" /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Search the site or use your favorite search engine for Date Validation Regular Expression JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, there should be `return false;` instead of just `false;`

Comment: It doesn't change. When I don't write any date, it gives alert but when I write 121313 doesn't give any error or 32/12/2002 doesn't give any error.

Comment: I changed it but nothing changed. It doesn't give any error when I give invalid dates such as 12 or 12/14/2002.

Answer (score 0):

array=date.split('/');
you get three values if the date is right. you can do whatever you want to do with them.

```
array=date.split('/');
if(array.length!=3)
{
alert('Not a valid date');
return false;
}
if(parseInt(array[0])>31)
{
alert('Not a valid day');
return false;
}
etc etc.
```

Comment: what you want to do in validation?

Answer (score 0):

Use the regular expression that is easier.

Put into your codes this:

Date in this format: mm/dd/yyyy

^(0[1-9]|1[012])- /.- /.\d\d$